# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sshagent' found among steps?

Tags: git, jenkins, runtime-error

In my Jenkins declarative pipeline I have the following:

```
 pipeline {

   stages {
     stage('Checkout') {
       // clone using git
     }
     stage('Merge') {
       // need to merge dev to master
       merge()
     }
  }
}

def merge() {
  sshagent(credentials : ['git-credentials-id']) {
  sh "git push origin master"
}
```

when running the pipeline I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sshagent' found among steps?
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to install [SSH Agent Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/).